# How to delete all empty buffers in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have something like 120 buffers open in Vim right now. About 50% of these buffers are empty files. I would like to somehow use the `:bufdo!` command to close all the buffers that are empty. Is there a way I can say:

```
:bufdo! ‹cmd›
```

Where `‹cmd›` is a conditional command that `:bdelete`s the current buffer *if* the length/size of that buffer is zero?

Comment: Note that `:bufdo`-argument command must not add or delete buffers (see `:help :bufdo`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only thing that I can think of for this is to make a function that
reports if the buffer is empty or not. Something like this:

```
function! BufferIsEmpty()
    return line('$') == 1 && getline(1) == '' 
endfunction
```

Comment: Similar condition: `line2byte(line("$")+1)<=2`.

Comment: @ZyX: Why not `line2byte(line('$')) < 2`?

Comment: @ib `vim -u NONE -N -c 'call setline(".", "abc") | echo line2byte(line("$"))'`

Answer (score 17):

Since it is not allowed to affect the buffer list with
a `:bufdo`-argument command (see `:help :bufdo`), we have
to use a more wordy yet fairly straightforward Vim script.

The function below enumerates all existing buffer numbers and deletes
those that do not have a name (displayed as `[No Name]` in the
interface) nor any unsaved changes. The latter condition is guaranteed
through the invocation of the `:bdelete` command without the trailing
`!` sign, in which case modified buffers are skipped.

```
function! DeleteEmptyBuffers()
    let [i, n; empty] = [1, bufnr('$')]
    while i <= n
        if bufexists(i) && bufname(i) == ''
            call add(empty, i)
        endif
        let i += 1
    endwhile
    if len(empty) > 0
        exe 'bdelete' join(empty)
    endif
endfunction
```

If you would like to delete empty buffers completely, including the
unloaded ones, consider (with care!) replacing the `exe 'bdelete'`
with `exe 'bwipeout'` (see `:help :bd`, `:help :bw`).

To test the contents of a buffer, use the `getbufline()` function. For
instance, to be absolutely sure that the buffer contains no text in it,
modify the `if` statement inside the `while` loop as follows:

```
        if bufloaded(i) && bufname(i) == '' && getbufline(i, 1, 2) == ['']
```

Note that `bufexists()` is changed to `bufloaded()` here. It is
necessary because it is possible to get the contents only of those
buffers that are loaded; for unloaded buffers `getbufline()` returns
an empty list regardless of their contents.

Answer (score 13):

I've been using the following function to do the job:

```
function! s:CleanEmptyBuffers()
    let buffers = filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val) && empty(bufname(v:val)) && bufwinnr(v:val)<0 && !getbufvar(v:val, "&mod")')
    if !empty(buffers)
        exe 'bw ' . join(buffers, ' ')
    endif
endfunction
```

It's very similar to ib's version except that it leaves the quickfix buffer alone (as long as any other empty buffer that is displayed in a window)